# Custom socket factory is not getting called on Linux - works on Windows and Mac

Tags: java, linux, ssl, socketfactory

Refer to the code below. It works fine on Windows and Mac but not on Linux. It does not call the MySSLSocketFactory class and as a result, the cert is not trusted. Any suggestions???

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

public class LdapBaseDN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://MyServerIP:636");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", MySSLSocketFactory.class.getName()); //MySSLSocketFactory does not get called on Linux
        try {
            DirContext ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
            System.out.println("Connected successfully ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //SSLHandshake fails because Cert is not trusted on Linux
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same Java versions?

Comment: Yes, sorry to mention that. I am using 1.8.0_181 and is same on every OS.

Comment: Try setting `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. It might log a reason for the failure.

Comment: @teppic The reason is that it is not calling my custom class for cert validation. As a result, it's trying to do a handshake and runs into error because the certificate is self-signed.